# Why do I have to add Lombok plugin, why adding dependency is not enough

Tags: java, plugins, dependencies, lombok

Im curious why do I have to add `Lombok` plugin. Why adding dependency to `pom.xml` is not sufficient like for example in `Mockito`?

Comment: @GhostCat there is no sample code. How can I add a sample code where is it technically question.

Comment: @GhostCat he means that lombok will only generate the code if you have both the dependency and the plugin installed.

Comment: @pipilam I could be wrong, but if I understand correctly: the dependency only provides you with enough to have access to the annotations and such, it's the plugin that will actually generate the code. I doubt it would be possible to have code generated without a plugin being involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand how Lombok actually works.

There are two parts here:

- the annotations, such as @Data, @ToString, ...
- that "plugin" that actually **generates** the corresponding code

You need a dependency to lombok so that the compiler/IDE can resolve the annotations themselves. ( annotations need to be imported, just like any other "element" that you are using in your source code ). But that only makes sure that your compiler / IDE *knows* that these are valid annotations.

The real trick is that later on, when code is compiled into class files, that "active" part of lombok is available to actually **generate** code.

This is similar to [java bean validation](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation). You need to import one JAR at compile time, so that all the different validation annotations are known, and can be used within your source code. But in order to objects being actively validated, you later need some other component that does that (the difference here is that validation happens at runtime, whereas Lombok is a compile time only thing).

And please note: that second way of "annotation usage/handling" is the more common path. In your example about JUnit, and @RunWith: that annotation tells *JUnit* at **runtime** to use that mockito runner class (instead of its own runner implementation). And that mockito runner then knows what to do at runtime with all the other annotations. Same story: annotations present in source code need to be known, for the active part, some component is doing stuff at runtime.

Sure, you can also use annotations to influence the build task, but as said, that is less common, and way more complicated.

Comment: Yeah. That was I meant. But Im wondering about `Mockito`. We've got for example `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`. By using is we don't have to code @Before method. So for me `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` as you said `generates the corresponding code`. With Mockito we don't need any plugin. Why is that?

Comment: Not at all. @RunWith is a JUnit annotation. The JUnit framework executes your code, and with RunWith, you tell it to use a specific Runner class. That runner class is then invoked, again by the underlying framework at specific points in time. I will put some updates in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Lombok is a so-called *annotation processor*, Mockito is "just" a regular Java library. Annotation processors

- define annotations that you can use in your Java code, and
- when compiling source code with those annotations, they hook into the compilation process and alter the input sourcecode or generate new code.

*javac*, the Java compiler shipped with the JDK, automatically detects annotation processors on the classpath and invokes them so that they can process their annotations and generate code. So when you add Lombok to your pom.xml and call `mvn package` (which calls javac), everything is fine: Lombok is now on the classpath and invoked by javac, and you can use Lombok's annotations in your code.

javac's main purpose is to compile *valid Java code* to bytecode. However, when you are writing Java code, most of the time the code is *not valid*. Advanced IDEs like Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA therefore focus on helping the developer even when their code does not compile. If they would just use javac as their only means of analysing and compiling Java code, they could not help the developer very much. Features as code outline, dependency analysis, finding a method call target, etc. must also work with invalid code as good as possible.

To achieve this, both Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA have their own Java compilers. For instance, Eclipse's compiler uses a completely different representation of the code's abstract syntax tree (AST). And it's mainly the AST on which Lombok operates. Therefore, Lombok has two annotation handlers for every annotation: one for javac, one for Eclipse. And this is the reason Lombok needs to be installed in Eclipse: *to be able to hook into Eclipse's internal compiler*, too.

Answer (score 0):

Before delving into why you need to add the Lombok plugin, let's assess whether adding the Lombok dependency alone suffices to leverage Lombok's features. We'll start by creating a Maven project through the Windows command line.

1. Ensure Maven is installed on your system and its bin directory is added to the Windows environment variables (verify by typing `mvn -v` in the command prompt).
2. Create a folder on the desktop (name it as desired).
3. Open the command prompt within the folder.
4. Execute the command `mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=my-project -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false`.
5. Navigate to the folder `my-project\src\main\java\com\example` and create a simple Person class with name and age properties, along with Lombok annotations. Don't forget to include `import lombok.*;`. As well, Within the main function, instantiate a Person object and print the result of `toString()` or `getName()`.
6. Inside pom.xml file, add the Lombok dependency, and include the following XML snippet as a child of the project tag to specify the main class:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.example.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

7. Execute `mvn clean install` in the root directory of the project where the pom.xml file exists.
8. Within the target folder generated by the previous command, locate the JAR file. Open the command prompt in this folder and run 'java -jar name_of_jar_file.jar'.
9. You should see the code functions properly.

The code works seamlessly, indicating that adding the Lombok dependency alone is sufficient to benefit from Lombok's features.

Now, let's address the question of why you need to add the Lombok plugin:

- Create a Maven project using an IDE such as IntelliJ IDEA.
- Add the Lombok dependency (omitting the need to add build>plugins>etc... to pom.xml since the IDE identifies the location of the main function).
- Define the Person class and its properties as previously done.
- Modify the main class.
- Disable the Lombok plugin and observe syntax errors on `p.getName()`. Re-enable the Lombok plugin to resolve these issues.

I hope you get the idea :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).