# Eclipse Maven build succeeds, but project still reports compilation errors

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, lombok

I'm using Eclipse 2021-3 (4.19.0) on Mac OS Big Sur.  I have imported a Maven project (https://github.com/gavinklfong/stream-api-exercises) and have verified the right JDK is selected (v 11)

[image]

When I right-click on my project, select "Run" -> "Maven" and specify a goal of install, everythign reports successful in the console output.  However, I see compilation errors next to certain lines

[image]

One for example, complains "The method getCategory is undefined for the type Product."  Below is the Product class

```
package space.gavinklfong.demo.streamapi.models;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;
import lombok.With;

@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String category;
    
    @With
    private Double price;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "products")
    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<Order> orders;
    
}
```

How do I configure my Maven project in Eclipse to use the same compiler/build path that is being used when I execute a Run -> Maven build command from Eclipse?

Comment: This question has already a correct answer. So why the bounty?

Answer (score 3):

These methods are generated by Project Lombok, as you can see by the import statements and annotations.

Lombok requires a plugin which you need to install in your IDE, since Eclipse currently doesn’t see the lombok generated code.

See for reference: [How to add Lombok plugin to eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52553693/how-to-add-lombok-plugin-to-eclipse) and [Why do I have to add Lombok plugin, why adding dependency is not enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52183837/why-do-i-have-to-add-lombok-plugin-why-adding-dependency-is-not-enough)

Comment: I added the plugin to Eclipse, per your link -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52553693/how-to-add-lombok-plugin-to-eclipse, restarted Eclipse, but the compile error in the editor remain.

Comment: @Dave Are you sure you installed Lombok correctly in Eclipse? How did you verify that exactly? The mentioned link refers to a question, not an answer. Better follow the documentation of the Lombok project.

Comment: The question i linked has a comment pointing to the official setup: https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse
If you follow that, your project should work.

Answer (score 0):

Lombok is an Annotation preprocessor. It is not enough to add it as an dependency (well for an compilation through maven it is).

After you added Lombok to your dependencies, it is listed below **Maven Dependencies** in your hierarchy. Double click the `lombok.jar` and an funny installer opens (given that you've added Java to your $PATH). Install Lombok for eclipse, it takes usually less than a second (no apparent confirmation pops up). Just close the installer and it should work right away.

In some cases you might want to clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've set up [Eclipse](https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse) already, I think you'd also need to setup [Maven](https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven).
When looking at the relevant [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/gavinklfong/stream-api-exercises/blob/main/pom.xml), it's unclear which version it is; this should be:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.24</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

See the [change log](https://projectlombok.org/changelog); when the version is too old, JDK11 won't be compatible.

Annotation processing also needs to be enabled:

[image: screenshot]

When the IDE knows about the generated sources, it should know about the getters & setters. The "Enable processing in editor" checkbox likely isn't enabled. Run `Project` > `Clean`, once enabled.